# WireGuard peer sends init messages to server; server doesn't receive

Tags: networking, wireguard

Table of Contents: Context; Peer wg0.conf excerpts; Server wg0.conf excerpts; tshark packet sniffer output.

Context: Peer is a headless LAN host that I configure/control via SSH from my Mac on the same LAN; server is on a VPS in the cloud, so also configured/controlled via SSH. The purpose of the peer is to forward input from another LAN host (just one for now) into the tunnel and return the results from the tunnel. The server is intended to take tunnel output, NAT it,  send it on to its WAN destination, and return replies via the tunnel.

Peer wg0.conf contents, edited for brevity:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.4.0.2/24

Table = 248     # wg-quick to use PBR for its default route based on:
PostUp = ip rule add not to 192.168.1.0/24 table 248   # not to local subnet
PostUp = ufw route allow in on enp1s0 out on %i
PostUp = ufw route allow in on %i out on enp1s0

PreDown = (*PreDowns omitted for brevity*)

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
PersistentKeepalive = 25
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = [IP of VPS]:51820
```

Note: the table 48 rule is to keep SSH traffic out of the tunnel.

Server wg0.conf contents, edited for brevity:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 10.4.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820

PostUp = ufw route allow in on wg0 out on enp1s0
Table = 248     # wg-quick to use PBR for its default route, i.e.:
# default dev wg0 table 248 scope link
PostUp = ip rule add to 10.4.0.0/24 table 248
PostUp = iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o enp1s0 -j MASQUERADE

(PreDowns omitted for brevity)

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
```

As for the peer, here the PBR is to keep SSH traffic out of the tunnel. I'm not sure this is the way to do it.

Just after the peer is brought up, the server response to `sudo wg` shows `transfer: 148 B received, 92 B sent` and that remains unchanged. The peer shows `transfer: 92 B received, 11.43 KiB sent` and the "sent" number increases with time. tshark shows this for peer interface wg0:

```
1 0.000000000     10.4.0.2 → [IP of VPS] WireGuard 176 Handshake Initiation, sender=0xBC9317D6
2 5.376117117     10.4.0.2 → [IP of VPS] WireGuard 176 Handshake Initiation, sender=0x6B160407
```

with an additional line, identical after the timestamp up to the sender ID, every 5.4 seconds. On the server, tshark shows no traffic at all for wg0.

I am not experienced with WireGuard nor tshark. It's been a struggle to get to the point when I could get both sides up without SSH hanging on one or the other during `wg-quick up` output. That I've omitted context that you need, or have made a head-slapper kind of error, would not surprise me at all. Thanks for any help getting the server to hear and handshake with the peer.

Comment: The thing is `not to 192.168.1.0/24` covers (i.e. does not exclude) the *encapsulated* WG traffics, so they are looped into the tunnel again (and again), which is why I mentioned in my answer for your other post that you should really just avoid setting `Table=` and any policy routing yourself, especially when you don't know how to do it correctly, since wg-quick's default configuration (for `AllowedIPs=0.0.0.0/0`) should work out of the box in your case.

Comment: On your WG server you can avoid setting `Table=` and any route/rule related PostUP= as well (just like the case of your client conf). All you need to do is to use `10.4.0.0/24` for `AllowedIPs` instead.

Comment: @TomYan re your first comment: would you have any pointers to something I can look at to help me understand the aspects of traffic flow within the peer as it relates to WireGuard encapsulation? ... I did change my server .conf per your second comment, but I can't test it yet as I'm working on the peer .conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insists on messing with ip routes and rules yourself (for who knows what reason), you can try something like this:

```
FwMark=51820
PreUp=ip rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
PreUp=ip rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
PostUp=ip route add default dev %i table 51820
# PreDown=ip route delete default dev %i table 51820 # unnecessary
PostDown=ip rule delete table main suppress_prefixlength 0
PostDown=ip rule delete not fwmark 51820 table 51820
```

You can replace all the `51820` with essentially any number you like (e.g. `248`), as long as it does not conflict with any builtin special or any existing number used in the corresponding context in your system.

This essentially mimics what wg-quick does out-of-the-box for `AllowedIPs=0.0.0.0/0` without `Table=` set. It's not guarantee to work since `wg-quick` also adds certain firewall rules (that are IMHO somewhat obscure) that perhaps address certain potential problems. Refer to the content of `wg-quick` if you want to add them manually (again, for who knows what reason).

---

Add-on -- an ugly drawing that explains a bit about the traffic flow of WireGuard:

[image]

Comment: The only reason I'm messing with routes and rules is to get a working peer and server as described in the Context portion of my question while being able use SSH with both peer and server. If there's anything in this answer that would keep SSH traffic out of the tunnel, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: The rule `table main suppress_prefixlength 0` is the key. It means that (when it has priority lower / precedence higher than `not fwmark 51820 table 51820`) all the routes you see in the `main table` other than the `default` ones will stay in effect. Traffics with destination that is covered by any of them will not lookup `table 51820`. `fwmark 51820` are the encapsulated traffics, which will skip `not fwmark 51820 table 51820` and lookup the main table too (because of the default main table rule with `priority 32766`).

Comment: (`default` = `0.0.0.0/0`, `/0` = `prefixlength 0`) -> `suppress_prefixlength 0` = (only) `default` ignored -> among traffics with destination covered by only `default` (i.e. not matched / routed yet because `default` were ignored), those that are `not fwmark 51820` (any other traffics) should  lookup `table 51820`, those are `fwmark 51820` (wg-encapsulated traffics)  should lookup `table main`. Also added a drawing in my answer btw.

Comment: Rougly `(1)` in my drawing corresponds to traffics matched / routed with `table main suppress_prefixlength 0`, `(2.1)` corresponds to `not fwmark 51820 table 51820`, `(2.2)` corresponds to `fwmark 51820` (i.e. builtin `table main` rule of `priority 32766`)

Comment: I replaced my table 248 lines with your suggested lines, except I omitted the `ip rule` command because it duplicated one auto-generated by `wg-quick` and that caused a `RTNETLINK answers: File exists` error. Your other lines also duplicated `wg-quick`'s but that didn't cause a problem. Result: IT WORKS! `curl https://ifconfig.me` on the peer (via SSH) returns the public IP of the cloud VPS. Then, from curiosity I removed all commands except my `ufw` ones, and it still works! So it seems the apparent mis-ordering of `wg-quick`s `ip route` before `ip rule` doesn't cause a problem.... Thanks!

Comment: P.S. `ifconfig.me` is a "what is my IP?" type of service on the web.

Comment: The lines in my answer is meant to be used with `Table=off`. If you are not setting `Table=`, you don't need any single one of them.

Comment: RIght, the `Table = 248` was one of the lines I removed, so I'm left with the default `Table = auto`. Only my `ufw` commands remain.